Does Blender have a built-in basic material library?
I'm an absolute Blender Noob and was wondering if Blender has a basic material library built-in. I understand that I could make my own materials, but that's right now way over my head. I am looking for some basic wood materials and textures that I can use as a starting point, without having to re-invent the wheel.

No it doesn't, but there are many free resources online and some addons such as Blenderkit which can automatically download the textures for you.

Blender Studio released the Charge materiel library; it's phenomenal.  Highly recommend looking up some tutorials on the Asset browser, it's super useful.

Yes, it does. There’s a built-in add-on called “Material Library” that you can enable. Once you have, it shows up in a panel under the Materials tab of the Properties editor. Select the “Sample materials” bank.
You may find that set of materials, a bit lacking, and in that case, I also recommend the third-party BlenderKit add on, which connects to BlenderKit.com, an online database of materials, objects, scenes, worlds, etc.

I was about to close this as too broad for us. but yes, this is a very fuzzy area, and this answer is helpful in the archive, so thanks for holding me off.
